# Two meanings of $0$ in field axioms for $\Bbb Z_5\times\Bbb Z_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

The additive identity in a field is unique, and we call it $0$.

The field axioms say that every element except $0$ has a multiplicative inverse.

But consider the field $\Bbb Z_5$.  It has a $0$ element, and $4$ nonzero elements that form a group under multiplication.  All $4$ have inverses.  So far so good.

Now I am trying to understand the field $\Bbb F_{5^2}$, which I am pretty sure is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_5\times\Bbb  Z_5$, at least as an additive group.

Just taking ordered pairs of integers modulo $5$ as the elements of the group, only $(0,\,0)$ is the additive identity.  Going with what I think are the usual definitions, however, $(0,\,0)$ is not the only element of the field that has no multiplicative inverse.  $(x,\,0)$ and $(0,\,y)$ also have no multiplicative inverses, making $9$ elements that are not invertible.

Does that mean $\Bbb Z_5\times\Bbb  Z_5$ is not a field as I am thinking of it?  Or are we supposed to consider "nonzero elements" of a field to not be all but one element?

If I take the multiplicative group of nonzero elements of $\Bbb Z_5$ and square *that*, then I get a multiplicative group with $16$ elements instead of $24$ and everything else seems to work.  But it seems as if I am missing some understanding of the field axioms. Where did I go off the rails?

**EDIT**: If I understand the comments correctly I have not defined multiplication in such a way as to make a field, but there is another way to do it so that the multiplicative group is of order $24$, namely to imagine it as $a+b\sqrt{2}$ rather than $(a,b)$.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_{5^2}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_5\times\mathbb Z_5$.

Comment: And the field with $25$ elements is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$. Its additive structure is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_5$, but the multiplicative structure is not. Neither $\mathbb{Z}_5\times\mathbb{Z}_5$ nor $\mathbb{Z}_{5^2}$ are fields.

Comment: In the simplest interpretation of the ring $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, you have $(0,1)\cdot(0,1)=(0,1)$. In the field $\mathbb{F}_{25}$, you could identify its additive structure as the group $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$. But then its multiplicative structure is something else. One common way has $(0,1)\cdot(0,1)=(2,0)$, since $2$ is not a square in $\mathbb{F}_{5}$.

Comment: A quick way of turning $\Bbb{Z}_5\times\Bbb{Z}_5$ into a field is to think of the pair $(a,b)$ as $a+b\sqrt2$. Still doing most of the arithmetic (of coefficients) modulo five, but with the obvious way of doing arithmetic with $\sqrt2$.

Comment: And, yeah, you should denote the resulting structure either $\Bbb{F}_{5^2}$ or $GF(5^2)$. As others pointed out, $\Bbb{Z}_{5^2}$ is misleading. The suggestion in my first comment might also be better denoted $\Bbb{Z}_5[\sqrt2]$ even though that is also mildly problematic.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Understood, which is why I wrote it $Z_{5^2}$ instead of $Z_25$, but it appears they write $F_{5^2}$ instead for some reason.  Sorry for the confusion, I'll edit.

Comment: For example, when $(0,1)$ stands for $\sqrt2$, then it has an inverse $(0,3)=3\sqrt2$ because $\sqrt2\cdot 3\sqrt2=3(\sqrt2)^2=6\equiv1\pmod5$. Similarly $(1+\sqrt2)(1-\sqrt2)=1^2-(\sqrt2)^2=-1$, so $(1+\sqrt2)^{-1}=-1+\sqrt2$ in this field.

Comment: "for some reason..." Because $\mathbb{Z}_n$ means "integers modulo $n$" (except when $n$ is prime and it means the "$p$-adic numbers"), regardless of how you express $n$ as the result of an arithmetic operation.